# Time conversion incorrect in momentjs

Tags: angular, typescript, momentjs

I am trying to use momentjs to extract and do some time calculations in typescript but...

I am getting *incorrect* value for time as *11:51 PM*

I should be getting 4:51 PM.

```
const m = moment('2019-03-13T16:51-07:00');
console.log(m.format('LT'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected because the date-time string input that you are passing to the moment function has timezone offset in it. Moment will convert the input date-time to local date-time based on the timezone offset. If you want to ignore (or rather preserve) the timezone offset and get the exact date-time regardless of the browser timezone, you can use **[moment.parseZone](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/parse-zone/)** method.

> Moment's string parsing functions like moment(string) and moment.utc(string) accept offset information if provided, but convert the resulting Moment object to local or UTC time. In contrast, moment.parseZone() parses the string but keeps the resulting Moment object in a fixed-offset timezone with the provided offset in the string.

```
 const m = moment.parseZone(ISODateTimeString);
 console.log(m.format('LT')); //"03/13/2019 4:51 PM" for en-US locale

// or you can also use

 const m = moment(ISODateTimeString).utcOffset(ISODateTimeString);
```